# C# remote (exchange)powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

i made a while back an console application(in c#) which does a few powershell commands.
i connect to the (exchange)powershell with remote powershell.
but when the application runs;

```
RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectioninfo)
```

i get the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

the only thing i cannot figure out is why it was working before perfectly. i searched my solution, nowhere i could find a reference to that dll. i also searched my c# drive it was nowhere to be found either.
i restored my solution from my backup of 2-3 months old and the same error.
Can someone give me some pointers to what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
apparently something is wrong on my computer(I'm guessing after installing the Beta of VS11)

anyhow, after using the project on a different machine where VS2010 is installed it worked just fine.

Comment: i deinstalled Beta 11 and repaired(reinstalled) VS2010 and it worked again. i blame microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading.

I had got the error, as I used the reference to the System.Management.Automation.dll Version 3.0.0.0 (which means PowerShell 3.0).

The issue is, the Exchange Server 2007/2010 isn't compatible with PowerShell 3.0, so you must bind the reference to the System.Management.Automation.dll version 1.0.0.0 (Windows PowerShell 2.0).

Answer (score -1):

1. Check all project references
2. Check **app.config**
3. Have a look [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1664323.aspx/1)

---

UPDATES

Have a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929)

Comment: My References dont have that certain DLL in it, my app.config doesnt contain a reference either. and on that link i was unable to get any helpull information. the whole DLL doesnt exist on my system

Comment: Where can i find this DLL ? i tried searching the internet but couldnt find it, searched all my HDD's (dir /s Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll) and no results.

Comment: Try to re-install PowerShell as well and may be some of Windows Services are down...

Comment: According to the KB it does not apply to my OS(server2008R2), further more in the included files the DLL is not mentioned either. Anyhow thank you in anycase for all of the effort you are putting into my issue, i appreciate it! Got any other leads ? :)